# Does optimizing for a two word keyword also cover all intermediary words?

Tags: seo, keywords

If my website is at the top of the search engine results (google.co.in) for a particular keyword ("Mobile Van").   Will my optimizations for that automatically cover all intermediary keywords like "mobile display van" or "mobile * van"?

Or do I need to target other keywords separately?

Comment: Search is not about keywords. Search engines do not make search term matches and has not for a very very long time. LSI is used. Search is about whole language. If your content is about mobile vans, it will be found for appropriate searches. If your content is not about mobile display vans, then it will not be found. Write appropriate content for your site, for users and not for machines. Do not target keywords. Target topics.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109487/seo-vs-content-writing-should-writers-follow-seo/109491#109491 https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106761/is-word-count-a-large-ranking-factor-for-google/106845#106845 https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105287/is-it-always-better-to-include-the-focus-keyword-in-your-content/105294#105294 I have written about LSI here quite a few times. I only linked a few. My point is search is not about keywords, but understanding content and matching search intent.

Comment: it depends on your content. `If your particular keyword is related to your intermediary kewords and your content covers intermediary keywords` too, than is ok. `If your particular keyword is related to intermediary keyword, but your content doesn't cover intermediary keyword`, than you should add additional content for intermediary keyword. `If particular keyword is not related to intermediary keywords`, than you'll need an additional url and a piece of content to cover your intermediary keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword targeting is important. There is no guarantee that just because you rank for "mobile van" that you will also rank for "mobile display van". But because you're ranking #1 for "mobile van", the chances that you will rank for other related keywords in your niche is very high.

Google selects pages to display to its searchers that it thinks are the absolute best pages for those search queries. So you may have the #1 page in your country for "mobile van", but you may not have a great page for related content such as "mobile display van".

So yes, you do need to target the related keywords to your page, or you need to create great pages related to those keywords. If you want to rank for "mobile display van" then you will likely need to have the best page in your country for that topic.

Because you are ranking #1 for the broader topic of "mobile van", it seems that Google believes your site is the #1 destination for the topic. As a result, if you produce great content for related terms in your niche you should do very well.

Answer (score 2):

What closetnoc has said above about matching topics to intent and targeting content to topics is correct. Think about 'topic' to mean buckets of keywords and those keywords don't have to cover every possible synonym and shaded nuance of keyword there is available, they just have to cover off what a person will search when enquiring about a specific topic. You will have a page rank for more than one keyword and if you can't get content naturally on a page, just create another page! Just ensure you're user journeys are consistent and everything is tracked.